# Matrix4 rotation won't work around x and y but works around z

Tags: c++, opengl, math

I am trying to make a single cube to rotate properly around all axis. I can move the cube, the view is perspective, but when I try to rotate it, the rotation only works on Z axis.

It's like X and Y axis rotation have no effect, even though I'm taking them into account. My rotate method:

```
        void Matrix4::rotate(float degrees, Vector3 axis)
    {
        float c = cos(Common::degreesToRadians(degrees));
        float s = sin(Common::degreesToRadians(degrees));

        values[0] = (axis.x * axis.x) * (1.0f - c) + c;
        values[1] = (axis.y * axis.x) * (1.0f - c) + (axis.z * s);
        values[2] = (axis.z * axis.x) * (1.0f - c) - (axis.y * s);

        values[4] = (axis.x * axis.y) * (1.0f - c) - (axis.z * s);
        values[5] = (axis.y * axis.y) * (1.0f - c) + c;
        values[6] = (axis.z * axis.y) * (1.0f - c) + (axis.x * s);

        values[8] = (axis.x * axis.z) * (1.0f - c) + (axis.y * s);
        values[9] = (axis.y * axis.z) * (1.0f - c) - (axis.x * s);
        values[10] = (axis.z * axis.z) * (1.0f - c) + c;
    }
```

My createTransformationMatrix function:

```
        Matrix4 Matrix4::createTransformationMatrix(Vector3 position, Vector3 rotation, Vector3 scale)
    {
        Matrix4 result;
        result.translate(position);
        result.rotate(rotation.x, Vector3(1, 0, 0));
        result.rotate(rotation.y, Vector3(0, 1, 0));
        result.rotate(rotation.z, Vector3(0, 0, 1));
        result.scale(scale);

        return result;
    }
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that they have no effect? What are the values of `rotation` and `result` at the end? Does `Matrix4`'s default constructor initialize it to an identity?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the problem was that all 3 functions: scale, rotate, translate where wrong and it messed everthing up. I fixed them based on lwjgl Matrix4f class and everything works fine now.